# Laravel Fzaninotto Faker Seed File: [ErrorException] copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I want to create some files for my seedfile using fzaninotto/faker.

```
file($sourceDir = '/tmp', $targetDir = '/tmp') // '/path/to/targetDir/13b73edae8443990be1aa8f1a483bc27.jpg'
file($sourceDir, $targetDir, false) // '13b73edae8443990be1aa8f1a483bc27.jpg'
```

My seedfile for the files looks like this:

```
$factory('App\File', [
    'order_id'         => 'factory:App\Order',
    'originalFilename' => $faker->file(public_path('files/uploads'), public_path('files/uploads/tmp'), false),
    'filename'         => $faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = NULL),
    'filepath'         => 'files/uploads'
]);
```

And I currently have a public folder structure that looks like this:

```
public
    -files
        -uploads
            -tmp <- Here are some dummy files of mine that can be used by fzaninotto fakers dummy creation class
```

How do I structure my seedfile correctly, to be able to generate some dummy files?

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally hat the source directory as target directory. This works now:

```
$factory('App\File', [
'order_id'         => 'factory:App\Order',
'originalFilename' => $faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = NULL),
'filename'         => $faker->file(public_path('files/uploads/tmp'), public_path('files/uploads'), false),
'filepath'         => 'files/uploads'
]);
```